# What is the better way if at least one of some keys exists in a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I need check if at least one of a list of keys exist in a dict, I mean, I have a list of keys:

```
keys = ['key1','key2','key3','key4','key5']
dict_ = {'key1': 1,'key2':2}
# I could do something like
if 'key1' in dict_ or 'key2' in dict_ or 'key3' in dict_:
    print True
```

But I wonder if exist a more pythonic way to do this

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use Python's built-in [`any()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any), it takes an iterable and returns True if any of the elements are true, and it short circuits when it finds a match just like your chained `or` checks.

```
if any(key in dict_ for key in keys):
    # do stuff
```

Comment: The code uses a generator expression instead of a list comprehension to save memory.  The generator expression `(key in dict_ for key in keys)` creates a generator that will yield the same values as your list comprehension, and when a generator expression is the only argument to a function you do not need the extra parentheses.

Comment: Thanks, that is something new for me

Answer (score 3):

You could use sets:

```
In [4]: len(set(dict_.keys()) & set(keys)) > 0
Out[4]: True
```

Comment: Doesn't short-circuit. Also, it increases linearly with the length of both `dict_` and `keys` whereas `any` increases linearly with only the length of `keys` (average case). When membership testing is already constant time, why convert to a set? Also, just `if set(dict_) & set(keys):` would do it, since an empty `set`'s `__truth__` is `False`. (I know some people prefer the explicit `.keys()`).